# How to change format of float value(up to particular precision) and keep it float?

Tags: python

I have some float values, and I wonder how to change them's format(for example, up to :.5f), but not changing a type? I tried with `round(2, ndigits = 5)` and `return float(f'{x.5f}')`, but first procedure doesn't extend a number and last procedure just rounded it. Is there a solituion, maybe using standart library?

Comment: Of course `round()` will not adding trailing zeroes (if this is, what you mean by *extend*), since this is a representation issue but  has no influence on the value. So what is the question about?

Comment: It's about how to extend or round float value(in one operation), but at the same time don't change a type of value

Comment: @83demon can you give some example

Comment: @RajuKomati, for example  I want x = 2, y = 4.123456789  to become x = 2.00000 and y = 4.12345

Comment: For my point of view, this is a problem of distinguishing precision and representation:2 is not different from 2.0000 under the float data type; printing is clearly a string representation.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = 23.457413902458498
s = format(x, '.5f')
s
```

**Output:**
`23.45741`

Comment: Doesn't it change the type of  value from float to str?

Comment: @KAUSHAL MAURYA check your output for this number `x = 23.999889999`

Comment: No. it does not change untill you change the formate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
y =  23.999889999
idx = str(y).index('.')
y = float(str(y)[:idx+6])
print(y)
```

**Output:**
`23.99988`